# SQL Server on LInux - OpenRowSet function only has access to files in /var/opt/mssql directory?

Tags: sql-server, linux, openrowset

I have a file I want to import into an SQL Server 2019 database running on Ubuntu 20.04. The file resides in the `/proc` directory and I have done a `chmod 777` on that file. However, when trying to read it from a SQL Server query using Openrowset, I get this error:

```
select * from openrowset(bulk '/proc/loadavg', SINGLE_CLOB) cpu_load
```

> Msg 12703, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Referenced external data source "(null)" not found.

If I copy that file to the `/var/opt/mssql` directory, it will then work and I can query the file. Why can I not read a file in `/proc` but I can from `/var/opt/mssql`? Also, how do I get access to the `/proc` file from within SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](https://www.tecmint.com/exploring-proc-file-system-in-linux/):

> the /proc directory is NOT a real File System, in the sense of the term. It is a Virtual File System. Contained within the procfs are information about processes and other system information. It is mapped to /proc and mounted at boot time.

Save or copy the file in virtually any other folder, and provide permissions to access it, and you should have no problem.

Comment: I ended up adding a cron job that copies the file to the /var/opt/mssql and then it works.